# Django form changes on selection

Tags: jquery, css, django, forms

I have a large django form. It has a lot of data that depends on a field being selected.

Eg:

Do you have a car?  YES/NO dropdown box.

If yes, I want to show the additional fields make/model/year/cc etc etc

If no, I want to keep them hidden.

What is the best way to this? A simple show/hide div using jquery or is there something better that I should be doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should use a simple show/hide with JQuery on the client side.
Then on the server side, you would need conditional validation in your form's `clean` method, if you also want to make some fields **required** only if something else is selected.

For example:

```
class MyForm(Form):
    ...
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        has_car_required_fields = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
        if cleaned_data.has_key('has_car') and cleaned_data['has_car']:
            for field_name in has_car_required_fields:
                if not cleaned_data.has_key(field_name) or not cleaned_data[field_name]:
                    self._errors[field_name] = ErrorList([_(u'This field is required')])

         return cleaned_data
```

Comment: ye thats what i was planning on doing. Looks like I was thinking along the right lines (for a change) cheers!

Comment: I would like to know if this answer is still relevant for Django 3.1 or is there another way to do that